# Why is L an interesting random time for a Brownian motion?

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, brownian-motion

Let $B$ be a Brownian motion and define $L=\sup \{ t \leq 1 : B_t = 0 \}$.

My question is:

> Why is $L$ an interesting random time?

Durrett's probability book proves something about the distribution of $L$ and also defines an analogous random variable and proves similar results for discrete simple random walks.  But why do we care about this?  When is $L$ useful?  Why do I care about the last time I hit zero before $t=1$?